# Как заполнить ячейку базы данных через Combobox?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server

Я хочу заполнить ячейку второй таблицы через combobox, выбирая из первой таблицы.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что вы уже сами сделали? Какой код у вас уже есть?

Comment: можно попробовать привязать к событию изменения содержимого комбобокса

Comment: `Я хочу заполнить ячейку второй таблицы через combobox, выбирая из первой таблицы.` что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: я имею введу что выбирая место положение заказа по доставке например "аэропорт" из таблицы "location" потом это значение вводилось к таблице "orders" выбирая через форму "combobox"